# Else Part is not executing even when condition is false Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am working on a Web application where i am searching for student result.By entering student roll no i am getting his data from Database.I have Student Model and Students controller , i am getting input from form and field `name = keyword` . I am comparing $rollno and the keyword it is working perfect but the else part just executes when i enter `roll no 0` , without zero whatever i enter it show me the empty view and else part is not executing.

**Search function is in Students Controller**

```
public function search()
        {
            $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
            $rollno = Student::find($keyword);
            if($rollno = $keyword){
                return View::make('results.single')
                ->with('search',Student::where('rollno',$keyword)
                ->get())->with('keyword',$keyword);
            }else{
                return 'Nothing Found';
            }
}
```

**Updated :**

Thanks to Alex for clearing the question however I changed my search function to the below and it worked perfect.

```
public function search()
    {
        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
        $row = Student::where('rollno',$keyword)->first();
        $rollno = $row['rollno'];
        if($keyword == $rollno){
            return View::make('results.single')
            ->with('search',Student::where('rollno',$keyword)
            ->get())->with('keyword',$keyword);
        }else{
            return 'Nothing Found';
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to compare not assign `if($rollno = $keyword){` this is not comparision. it is wrong .  `==` needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, of all, you're trying to compare string with an object. You should add `->keywordRow`, just change `keywordRow` to real one.

Second, use `==` or `===` (much better) operator to compare. `=` is an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

```
$keyword = Input::get('keyword');
$rollno = Student::find($keyword)->keywordRow;
if($rollno === $keyword){
```

Comment: i changed the code to `$keyword = Input::get('keyword');
  $rollno = Student::find($keyword);
  if($keyword == $rollno['rollno']){ }` but still not working now else part is executing

Comment: @LaravelWarrior you got your answer.

Comment: @Anant not exactly Alex is not replying.

Comment: Suggestion:- based on your question this one is the answer that anyone can give, because we don't know what and how it is executing. You have to check at your end. Wait may be he respond. And you already marked his answer.

Comment: You can check contents of both variables with `dd()` or `var_dump()`. For example: `var_dump($rollno['rollno'])` and `var_dump($keyword)`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin that is returing the roll no like '9' , '88'

Comment: I don't know what should it return, because I do not have access to your app. What you should do is check both variables and find a reason why they are not equal. Also, if you're using `===`, both variables should be similar type (string, for example).

Comment: Actually the problem as i guessed now is i am comparing real no i.e roll no with string which is like '9' can you tell me how to convert string to real @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: So, you compare string '9' with number 9, correct? In this case you can use `==` operator (bad practice, but very common). This operator will coerce variable types. Or you could convert string to a number with `(int)$variableWithString'. Or you could convert integer to string with `(string)$variableWIthInteger`

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is:

`if($rollno = $keyword)`

Which means you are assigning `$keyword` to `$rollno`. So this is assignment is `true`. Thus, your `if` condition always succeeds and your `else` part has no meaning. You have to use exact comparison operator in `if`